# How to use phalcon devtools with an existing project?

Tags: php, phalcon

I followed [this tutoria](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/0.5.0/reference/applications.html#multi-module)l to create a multimodule project folder structure. I am trying to use the model creator in Devtools.

It throws an error saying I need to be in the project folder, which I am (`multiple/apps/frontend/models/`).

Do I have to create a project through devtools to use the model creator, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you are doing anything wrong. It could very well be a bug in the devtools especially in the case of multiple module support.

What I would suggest is you create a new project in a different folder using the tools and then copy the models you need created from one project to another. A bit of a hack but that will get you going until we find out what is going on.

Answer (score 6):

Easiest fix for this because you didn't use Phalcon to generate your project the .phalcon folder doesn't exist, simply create the .phalcon folder in the root of the project. That will solve the problem.

Comment: the project I had to work on had an empty `.phalcon` _file_. I changed it into a folder and it started working.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are in the wrong directory. Commands provided with Devtools need to be executed in root path of your application. If you create a project with Devtools it creates a `.phalcon` folder (along with others) in the root path. If you execute following commands.

```
$ phalcon project test
$ cd test
$ ls -la .
```

You should see .phalcon folder. All other commands should be executed from `test` folder. I hope this will resolve you issue.